# Correct way to implement a client-call to a long running server-side method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I am working on SOAP-client in WCF to communicate with a self-hosted WCF service for remote controlling a piece of software that I am developing. This software has a very long running operation (lets call it `Print`) that will run for several minutes, perhaps up to an hour. I am trying to figure out how to implement the method `Print` given the following requirements:

1. The server should be able to raise `FaultExceptions` to the client, in case something goes wrong.
2. The client should be informed ASAP should the connection to the service be lost.
3. The server-side process of `Print` should continue to run if disconnected, so that the client can reconnect and continue to monitor the process and abort it if necessary.

Since I am new to WCF, I am unsure how to implement this. I currently see two alternatives:

1. Make `Print` an `async` method so that I can "fire and forget" it until it finishes or throws a `FaultException`. This seems straight-forward, but I see this "problem": There is a client-side request timeout in WCF with default value of 1 minute, which also applies to `async` methods (if I am not mistaken) and which I would therefore have to increase significantly. This seems a bit like a hack.
2. Implement the `async` behavior of `Print` myself by splitting its behavior into a *non*-`async` method `StartPringing` that starts a server-side task for printing and returns directly (or throws an exception in case something goes wrong) and a client-callback method `PrintingFinished`. I could then use the callback `PrintingFinished` to signal to the client, when the print-process has finished or a use an additional callback `PrintingFailed` to send an exceptions in case something goes wrong. This implementation would be "hidden" behind the `async` method `Print`, so that it behaves like any other `async` method that might throw an exception. Here I see the following challenge: I will have to implement the whole exception callback-stuff myself, to handle exceptions that occur after `StartPringing` has returned (from `StartPringing` itself I can throw FaultExceptions).

For both cases I will have to work out how to detect, when the connection is servered (which I am currently doing using a ping method on the service) and then somehow get that event to throw an exception from within the method `Print`. Implementation-wise this seems more aligned with alternative (2), since I need to already implement all the other event handlers for when the print-process finishes or an exception is thrown. However I am unsure how I would implement this for alternative (1).

So which one of the two alternatives is "better". By better I mean the following considerations:
  1. Aligned with the "standard" way in WCF for implementing such a long running method.
  2. Maintainability and extensibility.

If I should consider any other alternative, I would be grateful for any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand of your problem I think if you need a real async communication with reliability to use a message queue like MSMQ. You can use it with WCF : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048(v=vs.110).aspx

Update

In your case, you can use a SOAP call to send print command to the server because it sync and you need to know if the server handle the request. After in the printing operation is long and async. When this operation finish (exception or not) it need to notify client(s). But client could be shutdown for example. For that communication a Message Queue is the solution, MQ ensure that the message will be transmit.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

If you don't want use MSMQ, you can implement a web service on client side to be notified by the printing server, using for example a UUID to match call and notification in a map in memory or in a Data Base.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you perhaps elaborate, why you think I need MSMQ? I was under the impression that a request in WCF is transferred and if not I would get some kind of communication-exception. To elaborate further on my implementation: I am using net.tcp binding and all communication will be on a local network. I don't know MSMQ (and I am new to WCF), but MSMQ communication seems alot more work to implement. I would like to go with an approach true to the KISS principle, since I only have one long running method (if necessary forget about the extensibility part of my question).

Comment: Just to extend on my comment and why I am hesitant: I already have most of the implementation details worked out with the net.tcp binding. The "only" missing (admittedly big) piece is the implementation of the method that I detailed in my question. So that is why I am hesitant to switch the binding without a really good reason to do so. I would be very grateful to hear your opinion...

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer. So lets assume I were to skip the `async` part after I started the print-process. My idea is to have the `Print` method throw a "disconnected" exception, when connection is lost. It would then be the job of the client to reconnect to the service and check-up in what state the print-device is (i.e. if ´Print´ is still running or finished). I have foreseen properties such as "Printer-activity-state", that a user of the client can use to check up on the state of the printer and act accordingly after reconnecting. In this case I would not need MSMQ, correct?

Comment: Yes a solution could be that : the client pull the state of the server with a delay. No need to wait an exception : 1 call to launch the print (server just acquits and use another thread) and after pulling a status service.

Comment: There are lot of ways to achieve what you want but the good way is to use a message queue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your kind help and advice. For the moment I will try to stick with what I have, since I am under time-pressure and don't want to start with yet another "technology" (I am only getting the hang of WCF at the moment).